# QuickSight PDFs truncating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have created data tables in QuickSight. When I go to export to pdf, it truncates the data to one sheet (could be a 1000 row table). Is this a known issue? I need to format business reports. I was wondering if paginated reports were a solution?

Cheers

Dak

There isn't much on documentation out there, so I literally exported to pdf. There are no ways of formatting the pdf to capture all pages